# Difference between events and delegateEvents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-events

I'm reading the [docs for Views](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) and I'm confused about what the difference is between `events` and `delegateEvents`. They both seem to be called the `events` method on the View object.

The confusing part to me is what the key should be inside the `events` hash.

From the docs:

> `delegateEvents([events])`  Uses jQuery's `on` function to
>   provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. If an
>   `events` hash is not passed directly, uses `this.events` as the source.
>   Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`

But events from the standard events are written differently:

```
var InputView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',

  events: {
    "keydown" : "keyAction",   
  },
```

So how are events supposed to be written? Can you combine the two syntaxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) is the function on the view which is called to apply the events from the `events` view property.

> Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`). By default, `delegateEvents` is called within the View's constructor for
>   you, so if you have a simple `events` hash, all of your DOM events will always already be connected, and you will never have to call this function yourself.

This is happening inside the [`setElement` function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) ([line 1273](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1271-L1278)):

```
setElement: function(element) {
  this.undelegateEvents();
  this._setElement(element);
  this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
},
```

**So the syntax is the same and both syntax works.**

```
var InputView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    // keydown event from ".sub-element", which must be a child of the view's root
    "keydown .sub-element" : "keyAction", 
    "keydown" : "keyAction", // keydown event from the root element
  },
});
```

Inside the `delegateEvents` function, the `key` (e.g. `"keydown .sub-element"`) is split using a regex ([line 1311](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1311-L1312)).

> ```
> var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
> this.delegate(match[1], match[2], _.bind(method, this));
> ```

The regex to split the event from the selector ([line 1227](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1227-L1228)):

> ```
> // Cached regex to split keys for `delegate`.
> var delegateEventSplitter = /^(\S+)\s*(.*)$/;
> ```

And the `delegate` function ([line 1317](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/8ec88604732944f197b352a6be22c8216ea9d3a1/backbone.js#L1317-L1323)):

> ```
> // Add a single event listener to the view's element (or a child element
> // using `selector`). This only works for delegate-able events: not `focus`,
> // `blur`, and not `change`, `submit`, and `reset` in Internet Explorer.
> delegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
>   this.$el.on(eventName + '.delegateEvents' + this.cid, selector, listener);
>   return this;
> },
> ```

Comment: What about when the key of the events object only has something like keydown?

Comment: @Jwan622 I updated my answer with more details on this.

Comment: @Jwan622 read all the `delegateEvents` documentation, the "Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`)." part in particular is relevant.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the reminder, I added that into the quote.